# Camel Conditional Polling Consumer

Tags: apache-camel

I have an apache camel application which runs as three identical services in production environment for scalability. I want to add email server polling to this application using camel-mail api. Since I dont want  all these three instances poll the server concurrently, I want to put some locking mechanism before camel polls. However since mail consumers are polling consumer, I can not use them in this situation. Is there an easy way to do this ?

In short, I have a route like below:

```
 from("imaps://mymail...")//This polls periodically
    .to(Processmail.class)
```

But I need something like below in camel dsl

```
   from("timer:mytimer")
     .to("direct:checkDistributedLock")
     .choice()
      .when(header("gotlock").isEqualTo("true"))
         .from("imaps://..") // can not use from here!!! 
     .end()
```

Comment: seem to be a good option, I will try thank you.

Comment: @DariusX. I can accept this if you enter below as an answer. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**pollEnrich()**](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) allows you to "call out" to a Polling Consumer as a step within your route. This means, it can be used like a "from()", but mid-way in a route.

**Example:**

```
   from("timer:mytimer")
     .to("direct:checkDistributedLock")
     .choice()
      .when(header("gotlock").isEqualTo("true"))
         .pollEnrich("imaps://mymail...")
         .to(Processmail.class)
     .end()
```